# formatting posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme, but I'm stuck in formatting the single.php.
I have in my posts a slideshow plugin which is load with `the_content()` function, togheter with the text of the post, and with `the_title()` load the title.

**that seen like this:**

```
<h1>the_title()</h1>

<div id=post>the_content</div>
```

the problem is, I need customize how it's display.

### I need display:

```
<div>theplugin</div>

<div id=post>

<span>the_title</span>

the text

</div>
```

I try to do that with `add_filters` but I wasn't lucky.

I hope you can understand my explanation, if you need more details, just tell me.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users can add plugin components to posts in the editor, they are usually added via shortcodes.

If that's the case with your plugin, you can add it with `apply_filters()`. Here's an example of how to add a slideshow from the popular *nextgen gallery* plugin outside the post content:

```
<?php
    $slideshow = apply_filters('the_content', '[slideshow id=1]' );
    echo $slideshow;
?>
```

The above code can be added into *single.php*, any static page's page template file or directly into *header.php*  to display on all pages.
If you specify the plugin you're using, I'll update the answer accordingly.

If it should indeed be called directly via a function, I second Ancide's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the place of where the functions are situated. Like this:

```
<div>theplugin</div>
<div id=post>
    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    <?php the_content(); ?> 
</div>
```

**Edit: I misunderstood the description of the problem. Here's my answer now that I understand what the problem is:**

The plugin uses a hook for `the_content` function. If you look inside all the php-files inside `wp-content/plugins/your-plugin` there will be a file with this code:

```
add_action('the_content','some-function-name');
```

This tells wordpress to run the function `some-function-name` everytime the function `the_content` is run. So you need to look for the `some-function-name` to figure out how to customize the output.

Comment: But the plugin is loaded with the_content function, thats the problem.

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood the question. See my edit for clarification.